# Allow Remote Extensions with trixbox

Tags: sip, voip, trixbox

I tried to find the way to log remote extensions to a trixbox server (behind a NAT) with no result.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Web UI provided with trixbox.